# React DND dynamic DropTarget by props

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I'm trying to use DND for 2 containers.

1) container have static data form axios => tasks list. 
2) container have only tasks which were set to user.

```
<Container id={1} list={this.props.tasks}/>
<Container id={2} list={this.state.userTasks}/>
```

When I change user (by select) X => Y I have to refresh data for **Container(2)**.

My **`this.state.userTasks`** is refreshing but child component **Container(2)** still have the same elements.

This is because I use constructor to pass data. Constructor is call once. I know it.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {cards: props.list};
    }
```

I can't use **`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`** into **Container** (child) because I have to update only **Container(2)** and this method is calling when I move element from **Container** to **Container(2)**

How to update Container(2) cards when I change user? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are you using any store/ state management  framework such as flux or Redux ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can reset state information of parent component where you are rendering `Container` components when user information changes

`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if (nextProps.userId !== this.props.userId){
      this.setState({userTasks : []})}
}`